# GeckoInputElement.Click returns System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am making use of the GeckoWebbrowser control in a C# Windows forms app environment.

I am wanting to call the click event on a button on the browser page, from a code event behind.

When I try an access a specific button I can find it by making use of the GetElementById command, however after assigning this information to the GeckoInputElement to call the click event, there is a null reference exception visible with this.

My code call to get the element looks like this:

```
GeckoInputElement betbt = new GeckoInputElement(wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("bet-bt").DomObject);
```

If I assign it like this I can access the element but still cannot click it with the GeckoElement object:

```
GeckoElement g1 = (GeckoElement)wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("bet-bt");
```

The HTML for the button looks as follows:

```
<button data-action="bet" id="bet-bt" class="action">Bet</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

GeckoInputElement's are for Html Input elements.

Just use GeckoHtmlElement:

```
GeckoHtmlElement g1 = (GeckoHtmlElement)wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("bet-bt");
```

GeckoElement and GeckoHtmlElement exist to differentiate when the browser is displaying non html. 
For Html documents always use GeckoHtmlElement.